# Howto update content author in bulk from feeds importer?

Tags: feeds

I am using Feeds and 2 importers to:
- Import content
- Import users

Now I want to link the users to their content. The type of content I am importing has an owner how needs to be able to edit his content. Therefore it is necessary that the user is linked to the content as an Author.

What is the best way of doing this?

I have a primary key of the content which I can save on the user of necessary.